# Convert request.post to scrapy.Request but callback not firing

Tags: scrapy

I have a working code in scrapy project but with request.post.

```
response = requests.post(url,
data=json.dumps({
"var_a": "var_a",
"var_b": [var_b],
}),
headers={
'content-type': 'application/json',
'cookie': cookie,
})
return response.json()
```

But when I am trying to convert it to scrapy.Request, the callback is not firing. I have tried errback, but that's also not called. Please let me know if anyone else has faced the same issue.

**Scrapy code:**

```
def start_requests(self):
    for listing_item in self.get_listing_items():
        restaurant_url = listing_item.get('restaurant_url')
        yield self.generate_request(restaurant_url)

def generate_request(self):

    headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'x-csrf-token': self.x_csrf_token,
    }
    payload = {'var_c': var_c}
    return Request(
        url=self.url,
        headers=headers,
        method='POST',
        body=json.dumps(payload),
        callback=self.parse_restaurant,
        priority=2
    )

def parse_restaurant(self, response):
    try:
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        restaurant = data['data']
    except:
        self.logger.debug('Invalid response, %s' % response.body)
        return
    
    loader = ItemLoader()
    loader.add_restaurant(self._get_menu_item(restaurant))


def _get_menu_item(self, restaurant):    
    subset = []
    for x_item in self.x_items:
        x = self.get_super_item(x_item, restaurant, cookie)
        subset.append(x)
    return subset


def _get_super_item(self, selector, restaurant, cookie):
    yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url,
               method='POST',
               body={
                     "var_a": "var_a",
                     "var_b": "var_b",
                 },
               headers={
                     'content-type': 'application/json',
                     'cookie': cookie,
                     'x-csrf-token': 'x'
                 },
               callback=self._get_super_item_v2,
               )


def _get_super_item_v2(self, response):  # not being called
    print('resp:', response.json())
```

Comment: Show us the scrapy code so we can help you to debug it

Comment: Hi @SuperUser I have edited the code. Please have a look.

Comment: @Alexander due to proprietary reasons, I can't. But to simplify things, get_menu is inside parse_restaurant(self, response) method, which is a callback for main method (used by start_requests).  And you can ignore cookie var.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that none of the requests that you create in the `_get_super_menu_item()` method are ever dispatched to the crawler and so they are never actually made at all.

A scrapy Request object is just a container that holds information on how it should construct a message to send to a url. Once a request is created it needs to be returned/yielded back to the scrapy engine for it to actually send the message request.

In your parse restaurant method, the last line is

```
loader.add_restaurant(self._get_menu_item(restaurant))
```

which means the return value of the call to `self._get_menu_item(restaurant)` is going to be the argument provided to the `loader.add_restaurant()`.  It also means that your this method does not yield or return anything back to the scrapy crawler.

Then in the `_get_menu_item` method you have:

```
subset = []
for x_item in self.x_items:
    x = self.get_super_item(x_item, restaurant, cookie)
    subset.append(x)
return subset
```

So the collection `subset` is what is returned back to the `parse_restaurant` method and used as the argument to the `itemloader.load_restaurant` method.

The contents of subset are determined by the output of the `get_super_item` method which is where you create the request objects.

```
def _get_super_item(self, selector, restaurant, cookie):
    yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url, method='POST',
                         body={"var_a": "var_a", var_b": "var_b"},
                         headers={'content-type': 'application/json',
                                 'cookie': cookie, 'x-csrf-token': 'x'},
                         callback=self._get_super_item_v2)
```

So each and every one of the the request objects made by `_get_super_item()` is added the the `subset` which is then returned and used as an argument to the `item.load_restaurant` call.  Following that your program ends because those requests were never yielded back to the crawler.

Assuming that there are no other issues the fix is pretty easy. In your `parse_restaraunts` method simply assign the returned `subset` to a variable and iterate through it yielding each request one by one.

> TL/DR: below is a solution/fix

```
def parse_restaurant(self, response):
    try:
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        restaurant = data['data']
    except:
        self.logger.debug('Invalid response, %s' % response.body)
        return
    
    subset = self._get_menu_item(restaurant)
    for request in subset:
        yield request
    loader = ItemLoader()  # not really sure what this does since it will get
    loader.add_restaurant(subset)  # destroyed once the method finishes anyway.
```

Comment: Perhaps... how would you suggest we do that?

Comment: @Shivanshu yes?

Comment: i am in the chatroom